# Add Id's On cook's distance plot

Tags: r, plot, outliers

Sample data:

```
ID sum    a  b c
11  2324  1  0 2
22 2242   4  1 3
33 4328   5  6  7
```

I ran a linear multiple regression and calculated cook's distance. However, during this process 3 na's was found and deleted.

```
fit  <-  step(lm (Sum~
             a
             +b
             +c
             )
             na.action=na.omit
             ), direction="backward")
```

I have tryed "with":

```
window()
with(data, plot (ID, cooks.distance(fit)))
par(opar)
```

And got this:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

that's beacuse of the na's. Any solution? 
Thank's.

Comment: lm will use na.exclude(data.frame), why don't you fit the model with NAs exluded already?

Comment: can you explain? "why don't you fit the model with NAs exluded already"

Comment: data <- read.delim(file = textConnection("ID sum a b c
11 2324 1 0 2
22 2242 4 1 3
33 4328 5 6 7
36 4567 8 9 NA"), header = T, sep = " "); 
data.f <- na.exclude(data);
fit <- lm(sum ~ a + b + c, data = data.f);

Then nrow(data.f) and length(cooks.distance(fit)) will be equal. Still, your code for the plot does not work but your original problem is solved.